# how to insert structure into ast by comment mark Golang

Tags: go, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Good day everyone!

There is a file that I parsed using AST.
The goal is to insert my structure in the right place in the file (there is markup in the form of comments in the file)

```
package app

import (
    some imports
)

// #comment1
type serviceProvider struct {
    // #comment1
    some structure

    // #comment2

    // #comment3
# I need insert structure here

    // #comment4

}
```

the difficulty is that this necessary comment(comment3) is located inside the structure

I'm trying with help ast.Inspect, but it doesn't come out yet

and tried other libraries -  dst,astutil

```
var myStructNode = &ast.TypeSpec{
    Name: ast.NewIdent("MyStruct"),
    Type: &ast.StructType{
        Fields: &ast.FieldList{
            List: []*ast.Field{
                {
                    Names: []*ast.Ident{ast.NewIdent("Name")},
                    Type:  &ast.Ident{Name: "string"},
                },
                {
                    Names: []*ast.Ident{ast.NewIdent("Age")},
                    Type:  &ast.Ident{Name: "int"},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

astutil.Apply(f, nil, func(c *astutil.Cursor) bool {
    n := c.Node()
    switch x := n.(type) {
    case *ast.Comment:
        fmt.Println(x.Text)
        if x.Text == "// comment3" {
            fmt.Println("here")
            c.InsertAfter(myStructNode)
        }
    }

    return true
})
```

return :panic:

> reflect.Set: value of type *ast.TypeSpec is not assignable to type
> *ast.Comment [recovered]
> panic: reflect.Set: value of type *ast.TypeSpec is not assignable to type *ast.Comment